# can't install ubuntu on asus n551nw

Tags: laptop, asus

can't install ubuntu on asus n551nw
15.04
15.10
16.04
16.10
all flavors Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Mint ... and nothing work.
Everything hangs at some point during installation

Comment: Please, provide more information about your system, like RAM, disk space, processor, etc. Also, tell to us, at which point the installation hangs. Best regards.

Comment: I just tried Antergos linux and almost the same problem. Live USB work with nomodeset then installation is ok and hangs after login, some times cpu fan works on full speed.

Comment: Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
System Name ASUS-N551VW
System Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model N551VW

Comment: This could be related to the graphics card, or a bad disk sector. Please, try reading the posts found here: [Hang after login](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=hang+after+login). These could be helpful.

Comment: the bad disk isn't the problem for sure because I have been tried on many disks, on different partitions and today on new Samsung SSD  and always the same problem.
Graphics is a problem, but how to solve I have no idea,  btw mate desktop on Arch work with awful graphic performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have g551vw and use this for install ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS,

the problem was with nouveau Graphics Drivers, so I disabled it in the booting process by adding the code below to the end of Linux kernel flags in grub :

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

When the GRUB boot menu appears: Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the `E` key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` the parameter to the end of the Linux line ... Then press `F10` to boot.

[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1070307/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-on-loading-installation-from-bootable-usb)

Comment: This is related to some Nvidia card, not the motherboard. OP never mentioned that they use Nvidia.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with this laptop model. And with this method, my problem was solved